# spritekit texture animation with reverse on half of the way

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit, skaction

Looking for a solution on how to create texture animation on SKSpriteNode with stop and reverse on any frame it already played.
For example. Imagine a big lock. When i push and hold the button - key is rotating 10 frames until stops at the end frame. When i release the button key will be rotating back. Pretty easy with SKAction.animate texturesArray..., BUT i need it to rotate smoothly back even if i will release a button in the middle of the animation.
Lets say it will go frames: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
if i release on frame 6, i want it to go from 6,5,4,3,2,1 and stop.
and if i push very quick again when it will be on the frame 3, i want it to go 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 well, until i release.
how can i achieve this kind of animation. sorry for much text

Comment: The Apple demobot gameplaykit is using a animation with this approach

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: currently i am testing my own solution. will post later

Comment: Ok, if you reply to a comment, you should use @ + the user's name so they receive a notification that you replied. Is it possible to rotate a single image of the key instead of animating multiple images?